# twitter動画付き投稿ボタン

Tags: twitter

twitterで投稿ボタンをサイトに設置したいのですが、そのツィートに動画を埋め込みたいと思っています。twitter cardではなく、動画そのものを埋め込んで投稿したいと思っています。
動画自体はサーバー上にあるものではなく、ユーザーがポストする形にしたいです。
やり方ご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Comment: Twitter Cardではなく[添付ファイルとして動画を投稿させたい](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/uploading-media/chunked-media-upload)ということでしょうか。どういったサイトで用いるかによっては変わってきますが当然ながら一般的なツイートボタンとは違ってアプリ連携が必要ですし気になるところはあるのですが……

Comment: 埋め込む動画はサーバにあるものを想定していますか？それとも、ユーザが（Twitterへ）アップロードするというのを想定していますか？

Answer (score 2):

Twitter API の `media/upload` エンドポイントを用いることで、画像、動画や GIF アニメーションなどのメディアオブジェクトをアップロードすることが出来ます。

`media/upload` エンドポイントを使い動画をアップロードする手順は、以下のようになっています。

1. [`INIT` コマンド](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload-init)を使用し、アップロードする動画のサイズや MIME タイプなどの情報を渡します。この API 応答で返されるメディア識別子 (`media_id`) は、後続リクエストの実行時に必要です。
2. [`APPEND` コマンド](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload-append)を使用し、動画のアップロードを行ないます。動画は分割してアップロードすることが可能です。もし動画を分割してアップロードする場合、分割した数だけ [`APPEND` コマンド](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload-append)を用いたリクエストを行なわなければなりません。
3. 動画のアップロードが完了した後、[`FINALIZE` コマンド](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload-finalize)を使用し、アップロードが完了したことを知らせます。もし、 [`FINALIZE` コマンド](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload-finalize)の応答に `processing_info` フィールドが含まれる場合、[`STATUS` コマンド](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/get-media-upload-status)を使い、[`STATUS` コマンド](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/get-media-upload-status)が `succeeded` を返すまで待機します。この手順が完了すれば、`media_id` を他のエンドポイントで使用することが出来ます。

このエンドポイントに関するより詳しい情報は、[Twitter のドキュメント](https://developer.twitter.com/ja/docs/media/upload-media/overview)に書かれているので、一度読んでみると良いと思います。また、非同期的にサイズの大きいメディアファイルをアップロードするコードのサンプルが [GitHub に存在する](https://github.com/twitterdev/large-video-upload-python)ため、コードを記述するときの参考になるかもしれません。

---

参考:

- [メディアのアップロード 概要 — Twitter Developers](https://developer.twitter.com/ja/docs/media/upload-media/overview)

Comment: この回答はサーバサイドからAPI経由でメディアを投稿する方法ではないでしょうか？質問者さんの求めているのは、「Twitterで投稿ボタンをサイトに設置し」、「動画自体はサーバー上にあるものではなく、ユーザーがポストする形」とあるので、サードパーティのサーバを介さずに動画を直接Twitterに投稿するものと読み取ったのですが……（違っていたらすみません）